# Is there any IDE (netbeans preferably) plugins for boost.build?

Tags: c++, boost, netbeans-plugins

I find boost.build v2 very interesting and easy to use. Are there any IDE (netbeans preferably) plugins available for this?

Off the topic : 
I tried to register with netbeans community but never received the validation mail. How can i get it sent again? I am interested in building a boost.build plugin for NetBeans if one doesn't exists.

(sorry if this post is irrevelant to this forum)

Thanks,
Kiran Mohan

Comment: I have wanted to use boost.build with an IDE for years.  At one time I wrote a 1/4 working implementation for Eclipse, but I have since lost the code.  I realize that boost.build is hard to get at first and I try to tell people about it, but no one seems to get it.  To quote Will Ferrell, "I feel like I'm taking crazy pills."

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with Eclipse as a custom builder. That said, I recommend using cmake instead of bjam (and I think there's some cmake integration in NetBeans, although I never used it).